# Cannot move row to the table without row

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have two tables and can move the table to each other. There is a issue . After all rows remove from table1 to table 2, it cannot move row from table2 to table1. Would someone tell me how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

There is the code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.draggable_tr').draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid'
  });

  $('.childgrid tbody').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var draggableRow = ui.draggable;
      var draggableTable = draggableRow.closest('.childgrid');
      var droppableTable = $(this).closest('.childgrid');
      var droppableRowIndex = $(this).children().index(ui.helper);
      var draggableRowIndex = draggableTable.children().index(draggableRow);

      if (droppableTable.attr('id') !== draggableTable.attr('id')) {
        draggableRow.remove();
        if (droppableRowIndex === 0) {
          $(this).prepend(draggableRow);
        } else if (droppableRowIndex === droppableTable.children().length - 1) {
          $(this).append(draggableRow);
        } else {
          $(this).children().eq(droppableRowIndex).before(draggableRow);
        }

      } else if (droppableRowIndex !== draggableRowIndex) {
        if (droppableRowIndex === 0) {
          $(this).prepend(draggableRow);
        } else if (droppableRowIndex === droppableTable.children().length - 1) {
          $(this).append(draggableRow);
        } else if (droppableRowIndex > draggableRowIndex) {
          $(this).children().eq(droppableRowIndex).after(draggableRow);
        } else {
          $(this).children().eq(droppableRowIndex).before(draggableRow);
        }

      }
      re
    }
  });
```

```html
<div id="table1" class="bitacoratable">
  <table id="table1" class="childgrid">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="draggable_tr">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Student 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="draggable_tr">
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Student 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="draggable_tr">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Student 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="table2" class="bitacoratable">
  <table id="table2" class="childgrid">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="draggable_tr">
        <td>6</td>
        <td>Student 6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="draggable_tr">
        <td>7</td>
        <td>Student 7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="draggable_tr">
        <td>8</td>
        <td>Student 8</td>
      </tr>
      </<tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Is the `re` line near the end part of the actual code or a copying error?

Comment: When you've moved everything out of the table, the empty table body takes up no space. So there's no way to drag into it, because you can't move the mouse inside it. Try using CSS to give it a minimum height. Or give the table a heading, and change the droppable target to be the whole table, not tbody.

Comment: You have a typo: `</<tbody>` should be `</tbody>`

Comment: @Barmar, it doesn't work

Comment: I was curious why you didn't want to use Sortable.

Comment: there are few typo's in your code as highlighted in previous comments. apart from that there are duplicate ID's in your code. Please use unique ID's and check. Example table1 id is used for div as well as table. Same for table2

Comment: @Twisty sortable on tables that move all row. I need to move a single row

Comment: @YChan you can configure sortable for the Rows with the `items` option.

Answer (score 0):

First, consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.draggable_tr').draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid'
  });

  $('.childgrid tbody').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var draggableRow = ui.draggable;
      var draggableTable = draggableRow.closest('.childgrid');
      var droppableTable = $(this).closest('.childgrid');
      var droppableRowIndex = $(this).children().index(ui.helper);
      var draggableRowIndex = draggableTable.children().index(draggableRow);

      if (droppableTable.attr('id') !== draggableTable.attr('id')) {
        draggableRow.remove();
        if (droppableRowIndex === 0) {
          $(this).prepend(draggableRow);
        } else if (droppableRowIndex === droppableTable.children().length - 1) {
          $(this).append(draggableRow);
        } else {
          $(this).children().eq(droppableRowIndex).before(draggableRow);
        }

      } else if (droppableRowIndex !== draggableRowIndex) {
        if (droppableRowIndex === 0) {
          $(this).prepend(draggableRow);
        } else if (droppableRowIndex === droppableTable.children().length - 1) {
          $(this).append(draggableRow);
        } else if (droppableRowIndex > draggableRowIndex) {
          $(this).children().eq(droppableRowIndex).after(draggableRow);
        } else {
          $(this).children().eq(droppableRowIndex).before(draggableRow);
        }

      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="table1" class="bitacoratable">
  <table id="table1" class="childgrid">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="draggable_tr">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Student 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="draggable_tr">
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Student 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="draggable_tr">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Student 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="table2" class="bitacoratable">
  <table id="table2" class="childgrid">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="draggable_tr">
        <td>6</td>
        <td>Student 6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="draggable_tr">
        <td>7</td>
        <td>Student 7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="draggable_tr">
        <td>8</td>
        <td>Student 8</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

When all rows are removed from the table body, there is nothing to render. The table and body essentially have a height of 0 and cannot be targeted for Drop.

As suggested, you need to allow it to be rendered in some way.

```js
$(function() {

  function makeDragItem(el) {
    $(el).draggable({
      helper: 'clone',
      revert: 'invalid'
    });
  }

  makeDragItem($('.draggable_tr'));

  $('.childgrid tbody').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var draggableRow = ui.draggable;
      var draggableTable = draggableRow.closest('.childgrid');
      var droppableTable = $(this).closest('.childgrid');
      var droppableRowIndex = $(this).children().index(ui.helper);
      var draggableRowIndex = draggableTable.children().index(draggableRow);

      if (droppableTable.attr('id') !== draggableTable.attr('id')) {
        draggableRow.detach();
        if (droppableRowIndex === 0) {
          $(this).prepend(draggableRow);
        } else if (droppableRowIndex === droppableTable.children().length - 1) {
          $(this).append(draggableRow);
        } else {
          $(this).children().eq(droppableRowIndex).before(draggableRow);
        }
      } else if (droppableRowIndex !== draggableRowIndex) {
        if (droppableRowIndex === 0) {
          $(this).prepend(draggableRow);
        } else if (droppableRowIndex === droppableTable.children().length - 1) {
          $(this).append(draggableRow);
        } else if (droppableRowIndex > draggableRowIndex) {
          $(this).children().eq(droppableRowIndex).after(draggableRow);
        } else {
          $(this).children().eq(droppableRowIndex).before(draggableRow);
        }
      }

      makeDragItem(draggableRow);

      // If Target is Empty, clear placeholder
      if ($("tr.empty", this).length != 0) {
        $("tr.empty", this).remove();
      }

      // If source is empty, add placeholder
      if (draggableTable.find("tr").length == 1) {
        $("<tr>", {
          class: "empty"
        }).appendTo(draggableTable.find("tbody"));
        $("<td>").html("&nbsp;").appendTo(draggableTable.find("tr"));
        $("<td>").html("&nbsp;").appendTo(draggableTable.find("tr"));
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 1px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="table1" class="bitacoratable">
  <table id="table1" class="childgrid">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="draggable_tr">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Student 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="draggable_tr">
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Student 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="draggable_tr">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Student 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="table2" class="bitacoratable">
  <table id="table2" class="childgrid">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="draggable_tr">
        <td>6</td>
        <td>Student 6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="draggable_tr">
        <td>7</td>
        <td>Student 7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="draggable_tr">
        <td>8</td>
        <td>Student 8</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here you can see a Placeholder is created and items are re-initialized so they can be dragged after being dropped.